# Code is not disabling the correct column row on table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Good Afternoon,

I have a table and this table has a couple of rows on it. One of the columns is a dropdwon menu. I want to make it so if a certain value is selected, then it will enable a field on the same row. Right now, I have it reading correctly, but it is only enabling everything for the first row.

For example, if i select a value in row 2 or row 3 that should enable a column on that row, then it would enable the column but for row 1. Any feedback or guidance about this is appreciated.

```
        $(document).on('change', '#correctionReason', function() {
            console.log("test1");
            var others = $(this).val();
            console.log(others);
            if (others == "22") {
                console.log("reading");
                $('#otherReason').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#otherReason').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
```

Comment: IDs should be unique, use a class instead.

Comment: Are you saying that converting #otherReason to .otherReason will fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, if you also change the HTML from `id="otherReason"` to `class="otherReason"`

Comment: This made all the rows become enabled. I just want the field on the specific row to become enabled...

Comment: You need to use DOM navigation to select the `.otherReason` elements in the same row. `$(this).closest("tr").find(".otherReason")`

Comment: Thank you so much.... It worked like a charm.